Chrome won't allow notifications
For some reason "my browser blocks notifications" - does anyone know how to overcome this?


here is an example: https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/286734778/your-browser-blocks-notifications?hl=en

what does learn more say?

it sends me in a loop - https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242? - do you see the loop?

it's like "here is the setting page for Chrome - here you modify notifications - but Chrome doesn't allow notifications" - what? :)

Alright here is the answer, frustrating situation with Chrome:


and I will leave smutty dot com there haha, to keep it real
